# Use ANTLR 4 to parse smali files

Tags: antlr4, smali

I am learning to use ANTLR 4 for parsing smali files.
I encountered a problem parsing the method parameter list, and I do not know how to describe the problem, so I paste the grammar file and the screenshot directly.
grammar MethodTest;

```
methodList : method*;

method
    :'.method'

     methodModifiers
     Identifier
     '(' methodParameterList ')'
     methodReturnValueType

     '.end method'
    ;

methodReturnValueType : primitiveType;

methodModifiers : modifier*;

modifier : 'public' | 'private' | 'final';

methodParameterList : methodParameter;

methodParameter : primitiveType*;

primitiveType : 'I' | 'J' | 'Z' | 'V' | 'B';

Identifier : [a-zA-Z_]+;


WS : [ \r\n\t] -> skip;
```

The given sample input is as follows:

```
.method public test(IIII)V
.end method
```

[image]

I then modified the sample input to look like this:

```
.method public test(I I I I)V
.end method
```

[image]

Then it worked fine.
This is what the problem is, how do I fix it.

Comment: People are *always* falling into the same trap somehow ;) [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/antlr/3271/lexer-rules-in-v4/11235/priority-rules#t=201612041106421585522)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
So, This is because ANTLR uses the longest pattern to match and finds that 'IIII' matches 'Identifier'?
How can I solve this problem? Thank you!

Comment: The real problem here is that the smali format isn't exactly context-free, so ANTLR won't be really helpful with that. Maybe you could get away with lexer modes, I don't know the format enough to tell.

Comment: I can't help with antlr4 specifically (the smali parser is written in antlr3), but I do wonder why you need to parse smali files? In general, you're probably better off using the dexlib2 library to read the dex file directly, rather than trying to go through an intermediate representation that's primarily meant for human consumption (smali).